Numpy geta mask of false positives from the given two vectors of y_true and y_pred
Given three classes (5,6,7) of two arrays:
y_true = np.array([5,6,7,5])
y_pred = np.array([5,7,7,5])

Since second element is false, how to return one-hot encoded array of false positive array like this?
y_falsep_class5: [0,0,0,0]
y_falsep_class6: [0,0,0,0]
y_falsep_class7: [0,1,0,0]

So the returned array will have dimension (3,4), where 3 is then num of classes and 4 is the length of vector.

How many classes will you have? If you have 100 classes you do not want to make 100 y_falsep_classN variables.

@jared Only three classes, their names are 5,6,7. No, I don't mean to define y_falsep_classN, it supposed to be returned binary array with dimension (num of classes, vector length)

I see Python lists, not arrays

@hpaulj sorry, edited

IIUC, use np.unique to get the classes, then simple broadcasting to identify the y_pred values that differ from y_true:
# identify unique classes (sorted)
u = np.unique(y_true)[:, None]
# array([[5],
#        [6],
#        [7]])

# set as True/1 the y_pred values that match the class
# and are different from y_true
out = ((u == y_pred) & (u != y_true)).astype(int)

Output:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],  # 5
       [0, 0, 0, 0],  # 6
       [0, 1, 0, 0]]) # 7


Note: if you want a dictionary as output: d = dict(zip(u[:, 0], out)) -> {5: array([0, 0, 0, 0]), 6: array([0, 0, 0, 0]), 7: array([0, 1, 0, 0])}

Using IMPLY Gate
import numpy as np

num_classes = 3
min_class = 5

y_true = np.array([5,6,7,5]) - min_class
y_pred = np.array([5,7,7,5]) - min_class

# Convert to one-hot encoding
y_true = np.identity(num_classes)[y_true].T
y_pred = np.identity(num_classes)[y_pred].T

display(y_true)
display(y_pred)
display(imply(y_true,y_pred).astype(float))

Where:
def imply(a,b):
  return np.logical_and(np.logical_not(a),b)

Returning:
array([[1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.]])
array([[1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0.]])
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.]])

